# How to predict whether the given sentence is grammatically correct or not?

Tags: python, nlp, prediction, word2vec, language-model

I am trying to create a predictive model where the model tells whether the give sentence is correct or not by checking the order of the words in the sentence. The model checks weather the particular sequence of words as already occurred in a huge corpus and makes sense or no.

I tried doing this with the word2vec model and removed the cosine similarity or WMD distance of the two sentences but that only gives the similarity based on the word vector similarity and not the sequence of the words.

So if we give the input as 2 sentences:

Sentence 1- "I am going to the shop"

Sentence 2- "going I am the shop to"

output should indicate that the sentence is invalid or with a similarity of 20% or less

Whereas the word2vec model shows 100% similarity as the words entered are same irrespective of the order. So i guess it cannot be used for comparing the word order. Any other suggestions could also be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not fully understood how word2vec works. It is trained as a language model but it's not. It's a way to encode natural language words to continuous space vectors, that can be used later on, for doing language modeling including other tasks as well.

In your example above, you get 100% similarity because the word2vec that you have used has been most probably trained with the "bag of words" method. It does not care for the order of the appearance of the words, only for the context.

If you need something to work out of the box I'd propose you to check if there are available tools in StanfordNLP (https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/installation_download.html).

Comment: Yes i did realize that too. I was just stating what i tried to do. But it did not work as the word2vec model only has the vectors of words which could be used for comparing the context and not the word order of the sentence. Do you have any solution that I could try for the word order? Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @RahulHalappanavar this is an entire field of study: language modelling. there are lots of possible models

Comment: As mentioned by @c2huc2hu language modeling is an entire field of study. Depends on what you want to do etc. I'd suggest you take a look at the skip-thoughts vectors  https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.06726. There's also a nice tensorflow implementation https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/skip_thoughts.
This model gives you similarity between sentences but on a sentiment level.
For "grammar check" only, I'm sure the stanfordNLP I pasted on my answer should contain a tool. Good luck!